# Setting TinyMCE's default content direction as right-to-left

Tags: tinymce, right-to-left

I'm trying to set the default direction of content in TinyMCE (version 4.0.12) from `ltr` to `rtl`.

I'm using `directionality` config:

```
directionality: 'rtl',
```

…but the editor seems to ignore it and still the default cursor position is on the left and the content is `ltr`.

I also tried to use an RTL language for TinyMCE, but got the same result with the default cursor position on the left and the content is `ltr`.

What is the problem?

How can I make TinyMCE's default content direction be right-to-left?

Comment: works fine for me: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vleaab

Comment: @Thariama: I found that the problem is in my `plugins`! `fullpage` plugin makes this problem!! Why?!

Comment: maybe that the fullpage plugin changes/overwrites this tinymce setting

Comment: Could you write an answer?

Comment: Note that also using the `forced_root_block: false,` may cause this plugin not to work in case there's a text not wrapped with any tags.

Answer (score 0):

`4.0.12` had an issue where the `fullscreen` plugin would cause unexpected behavior with certain other plugins. Updating should fix this.